# Python code for QPSK modulator

Tags: python, qpsk, array-signal-processing

Have any of you done anything like QPSK Modulation in python? I am in the middle of it and having problems in setting up bits? like odd and even bits.

Have you got any idea?

Regards,

Sam

Comment: I didn't quite understand when you say "setting up bits" ??

Comment: Welcome here! You forgot to ask a precise question. You've forgot to state what exactly you're doing, what the actual result is, and how that differs from what you expect. It's hard to help you.

Comment: hey sorry guys, for asking unnecessary question i thought i didn't ask this. I figured it out later by using numpy and  append function, i was stucked on iteration of array but now its ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using scipy by any chance ?

If yes , this might help

https://scikit-dsp-comm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sk_dsp_comm/digitalcom.html

check for functions "QPSK_tx"  and "QPSK_bb"

Comment: Thanks Sara! I was using the komm library, are you familiar with that to know how this compares?

Comment: @DanBoschen  . Nope. I haven't used komm library and was using scipy and MATLAB for DSP Comms.

Comment: I appreciate the reference and look forward to comparing them. At first glance from GitHub stats: Scikit-dsp-comm: 6 releases since June 15, 2017, 5 contributors, 89 stars, last commit Dec 8, 2019, and komm: 17 releases since May 14, 2018, 2 contributors, 23 stars and last commit 13 days ago).